# "Image Upload Button" section remove after click on upload

Tags: views, entities, media

I am trying to edit users's  profile page in Drupal 7. I have an image upload button there, but it remove (hide) after click on upload button .

But If i login with admin its working fine, means image upload section is not hiding on upload click.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in a custom module, this module will act on all users but admin (user 1), this will work after user saves/updates his account.  inside function there are two sentences begining with $form, first will hide user picture field, second will disable it. use only one. code:

```
// implementes hook_form_alter
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
global $user;
$uuid = $user->uid;
/*  check that user is NOT admin (No1) */
if ($uuid !='1') {
if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
//dsm($form);             
if (!empty($user->user_picture) {
    // Prevent editing a field 
    // hiding the field entirely on the edit form.
    $form['field_user_picture']['#access'] = FALSE;

    // disable update field on the edit form.
    $form['field_user_picture']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    }
 }
}
}
```